# Complie C++ in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc

This is my first time using linux..
So how do I compile something in VM ware Ubuntu?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

void main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
struct stat statbuf;
if (stat(* argv[], &statbuf) == -1)
perror("Failed to get file status");
else
printf("%s last accessed at %s" ctime(&statbuf.st_atime));
};
```

Comment: `void main` is wrong. `argv[]` is a syntax error. `" ctime` is a syntax error. One of your `%s` is missing an argument. Spurious trailing `;`.

Comment: @melpomene: Mostly correct, but `char * argv[]` is valid.

Comment: @KeithThompson I meant the one in `stat(* argv[]`.

Comment: @melpomene: Ah, I didn't see that one.

Comment: The particular code you're compiling isn't particularly relevant to the question of how to compile it. You might as well use a `"hello, world"` program. There are a number of serious problems in your code (and your second version is no better than the first), but there's not much point in discussing them until you're able to at least try to compile it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a compiler (gcc would probably be installed by default in any reasonable Linux distribution), and call it, e.g., from the command line:

```
$ gcc myprogram.c -o myprogram
```

Answer (score -1):

To compile, use a compiler (such as `g++`) available on your system.

(using g++, assuming your file is `hello.cpp`)

```
g++ -c hello.cpp -o hello
chmod a+x ./hello
./hello
```

Comment: `hello` is not an executable in your example.